# How to take data from a database written in python

Tags: javascript, python, database

I'm trying to take data stored in a dictionary written in python and send it to be used in a function in a javascript file. I've seen allot of SQL examples but I cant find any for python. This is the section of the database that I am trying to take the data from, specifically eventType, date, time, and compName. Any advice?

```
agenda = {'id' : num,
                  'eventName' : eventName,
                  'eventType' : eventType,
                  'location' : location,
                  'date' : date,
                  'time' : time,
                  'compName' : compName,
                  'attire' : attire,
                  'additional' : additional}
```

Comment: You should specify your question: Do you want to know how to (1) query a database in Python (which database? Sqlite, Mysql, ...)? (2) transfer received data from Python to JavaScript?

Comment: database or a python dictionary?

Comment: Oops sorry, python dictionary

Comment: is there a web server running with Python? You could use Ajax

Comment: Yes this is running with a web server